# How can I automatically delete a field value in my Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to delete the value of my field in Django model automatically.

```
verify_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
verification_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self.verify_code is not None:
        self.verification_timestamp = timezone.now()
            
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here I save the time in verification_timestamp if verify_code is not set to None, then I want to delete the value of verify_code after 1 min (for example save the value to None after 1 min), now what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mamareza already pointet out: You can do that with management commands scheduled by cron. Or celery is the way to go. That is the correct response to "how to change values after a certain period of time".

**But** I recommend choosing an entirely different approach. Just change the logic. When the user tries to use that verification object you could use something like an `is_still_valid()` function.

```py
verify_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
verification_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def is_still_valid(self):
    # returns true or false
    # true when timepoint now is below verificatioin_timestamp plus one minute
    return timezone.now() < self.verification_timestamp + (60*60)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self.verify_code is not None:
        self.verification_timestamp = timezone.now()
            
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When then the user tries to use that Verification object, you can just check if it is still valid or if it already "expired". Try to keep it in python is my advice here. Hope that makes sense

This way you don't need go for the rather heavy approach with eg. celery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use management command or Celery

**management command**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands :

**Celery**

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html